# Using prisma and typescript models in parallel

Tags: typescript, prisma

I often use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) in my typescript models:

```js
const ListingVehicleTypes = [
  "car",
  "motorcycle",
  "caravan",
  "camper_trailer"
] as const;

interface LISTING {
  vehicleType: typeof ListingVehicleTypes[number];
  ...
}
```

As such, `LISTING["vehicleType"]` is correctly inferred as `"car" | "motorcycle" | "caravan" | "camper_trailer"`.

**Can I express such restrictions in my `schema.prisma`?** Neither imports nor typescript utils are allowed in `*.prisma` files:

```js
model Listing {
    vehicleType   typeof ListingVehicleTypes[number]  // no-go
}
```

**If not, is there a way to "enrich" the prisma models with the type-safer typescript models when prisma-powered DB queries are performed?**

I can always cast the query bodies and responses to `any` but is there a cleaner approach?

*For what it's worth, I'm using the [`mongodb` provider](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb) -- but I don't think the provider plays a role here.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using an [enum](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model/#defining-enums) for this. But make sure to check if enums are supported in the underlying database from [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/database-features/#misc).

In Prisma schema,

```
model Listing {
  vehicleType  VehicleType @default(car)
}

enum VehicleType {
  car
  motorcycle
  caravan
  camper_trailer
}
```

Then in your typescript code you can utilize this as follows.

```
import { Listing } from "@prisma/client";

type VehicleTypes = Listing["vehicleType"];
```

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, thanks! However, `type VehicleTypes` is just that -- a `type`. And I use the const assertions to retain the iterable qualities of arrays outside of my type declarations (esp. when generating the frontend or when validating via a [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) schema). In other words, I cannot iterate prisma-generated types -- `Object.keys(Listing['vehicleType'])` of course throws `'Listing' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` I suppose that's where the link between prisma and ts models ends.

Comment: If you need to obtain iterable array from a type [ts-transformer-keys](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys) might help. I haven't used this though, so not sure what the limitations are.